# How to execute php function inside in controller using crontab Linux

Tags: php, linux, cron

How to access sendNotification function ?

I tried this , but didn't work

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/pro_name/paymentController` function=sendNotifcation

Comment: This seems not to be the full entry in the `crontab`

Comment: You cannot execute a specific function from outside a script. You can only execute a script. So you might want to implament a wrapper script that does call that function.

Comment: Did you use CodeIgniter?

Comment: @developer : no this is pure php project

Comment: @arkascha : can you kindly give little for me on that. how to write wrapper script for calling function.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: @developer : please check my question, i updated.

Comment: How to write a wrapper script? Well, a php script that calls the function, as simple as that: `<?php include '/home/user/pro_name/paymentController.php'; sendNotifcation();` You can then execute that script via your cron entry, so as said above you call a script, not a function from there.

Comment: Is the request go directly to  `paymentController.php`? or first go to `index.php` or other files?

Comment: I would advise to use a separate folder for such scripts, one outside the http hosts `DocumentRoot`, since those scripts should _not_ be accessible via http usually. The paths then are a question of your file tree layout.

Comment: Well, I don't know your setup. I cannot say what that "project folder" is. My comment stands: outside the files directly served by the http server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: If your file is named `paymentController.php`, include the extension in your cron command line. The `php` interpreter will not add the `.php` extension by itself.

Now to business: Command line arguments are passed to your script in the variable `$argv`. The argument `function=sendNotification` is available as `$argv[1]`. Modify your script to check `$argv`, and if it finds an argument of the form `function=...` to extract the name of the function to execute. (Or you might choose to change the call syntax to something like `paymentController.php -f sendNotification`, which is easier to process and more unix-friendly.)

If your scripts are mainly used through a webserver and this is an exceptional situation, a wrapper script (as suggested in the comments) is acceptable and allows the original script to remain unmodified. But if you're writing php scripts that will be used from the command line, `$argv` is the way to go. If the same script is executed on a web server, `$argv` will only contain the script name (in `$argv[0])`. So you can write your script to do the right thing in both cases.

Comment: "Modify your script to check $argv" its not clear to me

Comment: btw adding paymentController.php -f sendNotification to cron command didnt work for me

Comment: i used paymentController.php -f sendNotification and inside paymentController  i checked  $argv[2] value came as sendNotification so how can i execute that function now

Comment: Um, what are you asking exactly? How about something like `if $argv[2] == "sendNotification" { sendNotification(); }`. With proper range checking etc.